# Notation to define an element with maximum occurrence in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of sets of natural numbers which is as follows:

$A=\{ \{1,1\},\{1,2\},\{3,1\}\}$ .

I want to express the natural number with maximum occurrence. For example, 1 has the highest occurrence in $A$ because 1 appeared 4 times whereas 2 and 3 appeared only one time.

How to express this with set theory notations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write

$$
\underset x{\operatorname{arg\,max}}\left|\{a\in A\mid x\in a\}\right|\;.
$$

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max). Strictly speaking, this denotes the *set* of elements that maximise the expression, but if this is known to be a single element, the notation is often abused to refer to that element itself.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood it correctly, in this case $|{1\in A|1 \in A}|$=4. If $x$ is other than 1, it will less.Is it true? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @usr109876787: a) I had a typo in the original answer that I'd corrected in the meantime, the second $A$ should be an $a$. b) You're misquoting the result; the first $1$ should be an $a$. b) I failed to point out some errors in the question: You don't have a set of natural numbers, you have a set of sets of natural numbers. Also, the first set in your set is redundantly written and contains $1$ only once (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_notation; search for "repeated"), so in this case $|\{a\in A\mid1\in a\}|=3$. c) You can use `\mid` instead of `|` to get the right spacing.

Comment: I edited my question as you pointed out (set of sets of natural number). But how to express the exact number of appearance of an element in case of repetition? Is there any notation which says the number of 1's in a set $a=\{1,1\}$ is 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @usr109876787: Did you follow the Wikipedia link? The number of $1$s in a set is either $0$ or $1$; this is not a matter of notation but of the definition of a set. You may want to use [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).